# overlapping shadow with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

Hey i have the follwoing code in my document:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade[inner color=blue,outer color=white] (3,0) circle (1);
  \draw[fill=white] (3,0) circle [radius=0.7];

  \shade[inner color=blue,outer color=white] (4.8,0) circle (1);
  \draw[fill=white] (4.8,0) circle [radius=0.7];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As a result i get:

[image: overlap]

How to make the overlapping shadows from circles look more natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `fadings` instead of `shadings` for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out,
inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [blue,path fading=fade out]  (3,0) circle (1);
  \draw[fill=white] (3,0) circle [radius=0.7];
  \fill [blue,path fading=fade out] (4.8,0) circle (1);
  \draw[fill=white] (4.8,0) circle [radius=0.7];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: It might be advantageous to construct the ring in a slightly different fashion that avoids drawing a white disk.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out,
inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [blue,path fading=fade out]  (4,0) arc(0:360:1) -- (3.7,0) arc(360:0:0.7);
  \fill [blue,path fading=fade out]  (5.8,0) arc(0:360:1) -- (5.5,0) arc(360:0:0.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, i have not used tikz for a while so I forgot about it.