# beamer > beamercolorbox > Text with Shadow or Glow

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, shading

- This is a "fun" project.
- I want to create a `beamer` presentation with a fancy title frame.
- The goal is to have a black title frame with "bight colorful" text on it that looks like **neon** text (**glowing**).
- It's a bit inspired by the intro of the TV show "Stranger Things".
- Ideally, I want to stick to beamer's `beamercolorbox` approach to build the title frame template.
- I found some (partly older) related questions but I was hoping that by now there is a simple solution available. There seems to be solutions available to generate this effect for boxes but not for text.
- Question: Any idea how to generate a "neon glow" for normal text on the title frame with `tikz` and friends?

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
% Potentially Useful Libraries
\usetikzlibrary{
    shadows.blur, % "pgf-blur" package
    }

% Title of Presentation
\title{Presentation Title}

% Definition of Title Frame
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
    {
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[center]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    }

% Definition of Font Color of Title (Used in "\setbeamertemplate{title page}")    
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=pink} 

% Related
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315989
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401032
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493401
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315989
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446841

\begin{document}

% Title Frame
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}

% Normal Frame
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

### Related

- [Adding shadow to font in beamer title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315989)
- [Can Gaussian (or similar) blur be applied to Tikz text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401032)
- [How to apply the "glow" effect to a rectangle with tcolorbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493401)
- [Adding shadow to font in beamer title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315989)
- [overlapping shadow with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446841)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but a simple trick to get something that resembles the neon text. One can use the `contour` package and superimpose several contours of different widths and low opacities to get such an effect. As pointed out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140440), transparency groups are important when combining `contour` with nontrivial opacities.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{contour}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
 \foreach \xyz in {0.05,0.1,...,1.5}
 {\begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=.05]
 \contourlength{\xyz pt}
 \path[font=\Huge]
 node{\contour{red}{Test}};
 \end{scope}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some quick and simpleminded implementation in beamer (i.e. there are almost certainly better ways).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\title{Presentation Title}

% Definition of Title Frame
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
    {
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[center]{title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
 \foreach \xyz in {0.05,0.1,...,1.5}
 {\begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=.05]
 \contourlength{\xyz pt}
 \path
 node{\contour{red}{\usebeamerfont{title}\Huge\inserttitle}};
 \end{scope}};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    }

% Definition of Font Color of Title (Used in "\setbeamertemplate{title page}")    
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black} 


\begin{document}

% Title Frame
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}

% Normal Frame
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am currently not at a computer. Is your proposal compatible with beamercolorbox?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I am able to replace the title with some text that has these effects. However, I would assume that there should be some genuine beamer methods to achieve this without Ti*k*Z, which a beamer expert can most likely provide you with.

Comment: Thanks! That is a good start.